# Cross-region AWS Glue connection

Tags: aws-glue, aws-glue-connection

**What do I have**: AWS Glue connection in region A, RDS MySQL database in region B. I want to configure access from AWS Glue to the database.

I have peering between two regions. Security group is used for AWS Glue connection meets the [VPC requirements](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/setup-vpc-for-glue-access.html). Security group is attached to the database allows inbound connections from the subnet is used for Glue connection. It contains rules for NAT Gateway and whole subnet CIDR as well.

Output from `error` log group is

```
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [d]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [d] starting at position 16 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [thread]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [thread] starting at position 25 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [level]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [level] starting at position 35 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [logger]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [logger] starting at position 47 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [msg]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [msg] starting at position 54 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [n]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [n] starting at position 56 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [d]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [d] starting at position 16 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [thread]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [thread] starting at position 25 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [level]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [level] starting at position 35 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [logger]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [logger] starting at position 47 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [msg]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [msg] starting at position 54 in conversion pattern.
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [n]
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [n] starting at position 56 in conversion pattern.
```

Output from `output` log group is

```
Check that your connection definition references your JDBC database with correct URL syntax, username, and password. Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
Exiting with error code 30
```

How can I find the element in network chain which is wrongly configured? I'm not sure that the connection error is related to JDBC URL.

Comment: Having just dealt with similar unhelpful error messages from trying to setup a Glue connection to a Postgres RDS instance in the same region, it's possible that the JDBC driver may not be compatible with the engine instance: https://www.repost.aws/questions/QUpkrhcfkYQtS2adbjpQ7quQ/cannot-connect-from-glue-to-rds-postgres. In my case, I had to downgrade to PostgreSQL Engine 13 from 14.

Answer (score 1):

You can get more detailed logs in the output log group. By default, the test connection link opens `/aws-glue/testconnection/error/<connection_name>` CloudWatch log group.

Click on `Log groups` and open `/aws-glue/testconnection/output/<connection_name>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note for people who facing the same issue. My use case is to link Glue cross region with a Redshift serverless.

- Confirm the VPC peering between region A private subnet and region B are working.
- Glue role able to access rds/redshift(Secrets Manager also).
- Glue inbound security group set to allow all in all traffic
- inbound security group: allow redshift to NAT elastic IP
- Glue Connection URL jdbc must add the database name like jdbc:xxx.com:5439/{database_name}

hope it helps